# SAS no macro subsitution for env vars

Tags: sas

Hi in SAS I'm using these statements:

```
 %LET xls=Selectie_&datum._&hhmm.;
 PROC EXPORT DATA=work.selectie OUTFILE="&pad.\&xls..xlsx"
 DBMS=XLSX
 REPLACE
    ;
  newfile=yes;
  quit;
```

the file has been created ok: NOTE: "\SRTZZAPP0274\SASData\NNB\MFT_Output\Banksparen\Selectie_20161028_1118.xlsx" file was successfully created.

so fat so good.
But when I want to use this macrovar I cannot get this value. 
!NNBankdata is an environment var.

```
 %put &pad;
 !NNBankData\MFT_Output\Banksparen
```

so how is it possible to revolve !NNBankData also like it is working in proc export?

pad has been created to read a flat file with this value:
    NNBankData\MFT_Output\Banksparen
and put this in a macro var: 
    CALL SYMPUTX('pad',TRIM(pad),'G');

Answer (score 2):

If the first character of a filename reference is an exclamation mark (!) then SAS will attempt to resolve the first item as an environment variable.

As user 667489 mentions, the following should give you your path:

```
%put %sysget(pad);
```

An example of this in action:

```
data _null_;
  file "!temp\test.txt";
  put 'test';
run;
```

More information can be found in this SGF [paper](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings10/090-2010.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `%sysget` function to retrieve environment variables.